# A comparison between seem, look, appear and appear to be

Tags: verbs, comparison

Imagine a 12 years old boy who facially e.g. looks 18 years old. Which one of the following sentences sounds more natural in English:

> - He **seems** older than his age.
> - He **appears** older than his age.
> - He **appears to be** older than his age.
> - He **looks** older than his age.

Comment: I would think _seems_ can apply to behavior and maturity, not just looks, so I think _looks_ and _appears_ are the more fitting verbs for the situation you describe.

Answer (score 2):

> He looks older than his age.
>   He appears older than his age.

describes your situation with certainty by the observer

> He appears to be older than his age.

describes your situation with possibly some uncertainty or reservations

> He seems older than his age.

describes more his actions and behavior than just visually how he looks.

Comment: Thank you very much, Peter. Your response has been really helpful so far, but to make it a bit more clear for me, could you possibly let me know what did you exactly mean by: "describes your situation with possibly some uncertainty or reservations"? It is a bit ambiguous for me. :)

Comment: "It would appear to be..." has the meaning of "it looks like from the outside", the uncertainty comes from knowing how *something* looks is not necessarily how *something* is. There are several sayings which get used: "do not to judge a book by it's cover", "looks can be deceiving" or "all that glitters is not gold".

Comment: But it was exactly what I used to think about the verb "seem"! Then how can I differentiate these two from one another? Could you please help me with this one too and then make your posts an answer? :)