# "Be willing to" and "willing to"?

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

I have a sentence: "*They appear willing to talk to us*".

So can you tell me why don't use "*They appear being willing to talk to us*".

I think that the sentence in present participle can be written without "be"?

Please give me your comment for this! Thank you.

Comment: You are on the right track, but you need the infinitive: *They appear to be willing to talk to us.*

Comment: *They appear* in some manner, and the manner or way in which they appear is *willing to talk to us*, just like you would say "They seem tall" and not "they seem being tall".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A comparison between seem, look, appear and appear to be](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/106736/a-comparison-between-seem-look-appear-and-appear-to-be)

Comment: There is no such thing as a sentence in the present participle. There is a sentence that uses a present participle....

Answer (score 1):

A participle is a kind of adjective. It is relatively common to use a passive participle as an adjective, for example ***cooked*** meat. It is also possible to use an active participle as an adjective, for example ***sparkling*** water.

When we use an active participle to make the present continuous form of the verb, we put **is** in front of it, but this is not necessary if you are using it as a simple adjective.

The two sentences below are grammatically identical in structure- only the meaning is different:

> They appear **ready** to talk to us
>   They appear **willing** to talk to us

Comment: a passive participle? No such animal, I'm afraid. There are present and past  participles, not active and passive participles. Both can be used as adjectives.

Comment: @Lambie: Call it a past participle if you insist. It's what you use to form a passive voice sentence that could relate to the past, present or future.

Comment: A passive voice sentence? Ok. Here's one in three tenses: The apple is eaten by the boy [every day]; The apple will be eaten by the boy; The apple was eaten by the boy. Eaten is a past participle, used to create those passive voice sentences. It's best to use known nomenclature or it can be even more confusing, especially when the OP also incorrectly called this: /a sentence in present participle/

Comment: @Lambie: Passive Participle is *known nomenclature*: it's just not the particular term that you prefer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Participle. Note also in the article that the term **present participle**, as used by the OP, is also perfectly correct.

Answer (score 1):

They appear being willing to talk to us

The sentence is not grammatical.

The word "willing" is an adjective,

You can follow the linking verb "appear" by an adjective or a to-infinitive, not the -ing form of a verb as follows:

They appear willing to talk to us.

They appear to be willing to talk to us.

Furthermore, "appear" (in the sense of seem) is a slightly more formal than "seem".  The seem is more common.

They seem willing to talk to us.

Comment: Why is the first example not grammatical? Like “willing” is an adjective “being” is an adjective as well. They are both present participles, and, as mentioned in the other answer, a participle is a kind of adjective. So, IMO, it is unnecessarily complex but perfectly grammatical.